# How to capture a specific region of an inactive application window in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, screenshot, region

I only need a very specific portion of an non-foreground application window saved as a Bitmap, not the entire application window. I have been using this function to find and create a screenshot of my application but I do not understand how to modify the starting point and size of the RECT to process only a specific portion of the application window (i.e. notepad).

```
public static IntPtr WinGetHandle(string wName)
{
     foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
         if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(wName))
             return pList.MainWindowHandle;

     return IntPtr.Zero;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

public static void PrintThisWindow(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    // Create the Rectangle
    RECT rc = new RECT();
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rc);

    // Capture bmp from hwnd
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics gfxBmp = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    IntPtr hdcBitmap = gfxBmp.GetHdc();
    PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);

    // Dispose
    gfxBmp.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
    gfxBmp.Dispose();

    //bitmap.Save
    bmp.Save("Example.png");
}

//Whatever window you want to test.
IntPtr hwnd = WinGetHandle("New Text Document.txt - Notepad");
PrintThisWindow(hwnd)
```

I have tried manually setting the RECT with `RECT rc = new RECT(100, 100, 200, 200)`
I have also tried setting the location 'point' and size of the rect: `rc.Location = new Point(100, 100)` and `rc.Size = new Size(100, 100)`. Help would be appreciated, I spent many many hours trying to find a function that is similar that I could adapt but I couldn't find anything aside from CopyFromScreen: `captureGraphics.CopyFromScreen(200, 200, 0, 0, new Size(100, 100));` which works by starting at the correct point and size BUT it quite literally copies from the entire screen and not from a specific window. Thanks in advance!

Here is the RECT class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    private int _Left;
    private int _Top;
    private int _Right;
    private int _Bottom;

    public RECT(RECT Rectangle) : this(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom)
    {
    }
    public RECT(int Left, int Top, int Right, int Bottom)
    {
         _Left = Left;
         _Top = Top;
         _Right = Right;
         _Bottom = Bottom;
    }

    public int X
    {
         get { return _Left; }
         set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Y
    {
         get { return _Top; }
         set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Left
    {
         get { return _Left; }
         set { _Left = value; }
    }
    public int Top
    {
         get { return _Top; }
         set { _Top = value; }
    }
    public int Right
    {
         get { return _Right; }
         set { _Right = value; }
    }
    public int Bottom
    {
         get { return _Bottom; }
         set { _Bottom = value; }
    }
    public int Height
    {
         get { return _Bottom - _Top; }
         set { _Bottom = value + _Top; }
    }
    public int Width
    {
         get { return _Right - _Left; }
         set { _Right = value + _Left; }
    }
    public Point Location
    {
         get { return new Point(Left, Top); }
         set
         {
              _Left = value.X;
              _Top = value.Y;
         }
    }
    public Size Size
    {
         get { return new Size(Width, Height); }
         set
         {
              _Right = value.Width + _Left;
              _Bottom = value.Height + _Top;
         }
    }

    public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT Rectangle)
    {
         return new Rectangle(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
    }
    public static implicit operator RECT(Rectangle Rectangle)
    {
         return new RECT(Rectangle.Left, Rectangle.Top, Rectangle.Right, Rectangle.Bottom);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
         return Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(RECT Rectangle1, RECT Rectangle2)
    {
         return !Rectangle1.Equals(Rectangle2);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return "{Left: " + _Left + "; " + "Top: " + _Top + "; Right: " + _Right + "; Bottom: " + _Bottom + "}";
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
         return ToString().GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(RECT Rectangle)
    {
         return Rectangle.Left == _Left && Rectangle.Top == _Top && Rectangle.Right == _Right && Rectangle.Bottom == _Bottom;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object Object)
    {
         if (Object is RECT)
         {
              return Equals((RECT)Object);
         }
         else if (Object is Rectangle)
         {
              return Equals(new RECT((Rectangle)Object));
         }

         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code to get some part of the form as a bitmap?

Comment: No. It's to get a screenshot of a specific region of an external application as a bitmap. The code above creates a full screenshot as a bitmap of the named named application. I'm trying to find ways to modify it to only take a screenshot as a bitmap of a specific region of the named application. This would reduce the amount of time to create the bitmap because it's less area which is my goal in making this work.